# external HD doesn't show up nor mount on ubuntu 16.04 but it does in 14

Tags: 16.04, mount, external-hdd

First of all, I'm very new to linux as a whole, so please bare with me on that!

As stated, the issue is ubuntu 16.04 doesn't detect (nor mount of course) an external HD when i plug it in. I actually reinstalled the same version, and the problem remains. However, when I try it on a laptop with ubuntu 14.04, it works perfectly. On this same laptop I also have windows 7, and it also DIDN'T detect the drive.

I've been trying the different solutions proposed in this site and others for issues with mounting external drives, but so far no luck. Through fdisk command in ubuntu 14.04 I manage to confirm it's ntfs, just in case.

It doesn't even show up on fdisk -l, df or lsblk, so I can't use the "manual" sudo mount  , because apparently technically the device doesn't exist for ubuntu (at least it has no assigned label/direction, the message I get is that there is no such device). I even tried "faking it" (wrote /dev/sdb since the other hd is sda, then tried with sdb1, still no luck).

When I try dmesg, however, it DOES show up there. I copy output below:

```
[   48.663473] FAT-fs (sdb1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[  747.771706] nouveau 0000:00:0d.0: bus: MMIO write of 01c20001 FAULT at 00b010
[  749.816349] nouveau 0000:00:0d.0: bus: MMIO write of 00000000 FAULT at 00b010
[  751.233864] nouveau 0000:00:0d.0: bus: MMIO write of 03510001 FAULT at 00b010
[  751.598999] nouveau 0000:00:0d.0: bus: MMIO write of 00a60001 FAULT at 00b020
[  763.889421] nouveau 0000:00:0d.0: bus: MMIO write of 04720001 FAULT at 00b030
[  904.281268] nouveau 0000:00:0d.0: bus: MMIO write of 00a80001 FAULT at 00b040
[  904.883163] nouveau 0000:00:0d.0: bus: MMIO write of 00000000 FAULT at 00b030
[ 1009.646990] nouveau 0000:00:0d.0: bus: MMIO write of 04430001 FAULT at 00b030
[ 1010.641375] nouveau 0000:00:0d.0: bus: MMIO write of 00000000 FAULT at 00b040
[ 1013.134091] nouveau 0000:00:0d.0: bus: MMIO write of 04720001 FAULT at 00b040
[ 1020.921975] nouveau 0000:00:0d.0: bus: MMIO write of 04740001 FAULT at 00b030
[ 1286.160835] nouveau 0000:00:0d.0: bus: MMIO write of 03fe0001 FAULT at 00b050
[ 1324.005739] nouveau 0000:00:0d.0: bus: MMIO write of 00000000 FAULT at 00b050
[ 3748.169676] nouveau 0000:00:0d.0: bus: MMIO write of 04d40001 FAULT at 00b040
[ 3748.595180] nouveau 0000:00:0d.0: bus: MMIO write of 00000000 FAULT at 00b030
[ 3750.576516] nouveau 0000:00:0d.0: bus: MMIO write of 04d00001 FAULT at 00b030
[ 3750.799325] nouveau 0000:00:0d.0: bus: MMIO write of 04220001 FAULT at 00b050
[ 3752.383465] show_signal_msg: 9 callbacks suppressed
[ 3752.383476] chrome[2259]: segfault at 0 ip b397f9cc sp bfed2bf4 error 4 in nouveau_dri.so[b354f000+970000]
[ 3752.811471] nouveau 0000:00:0d.0: bus: MMIO write of 00000000 FAULT at 00b050
[ 3805.785489] nouveau 0000:00:0d.0: bus: MMIO write of 00000000 FAULT at 00b040
[ 3807.612750] nouveau 0000:00:0d.0: bus: MMIO write of 00000000 FAULT at 00b020
[ 3807.613021] nouveau 0000:00:0d.0: bus: MMIO write of 00000000 FAULT at 00b030
[ 3807.613281] nouveau 0000:00:0d.0: bus: MMIO write of 01c20001 FAULT at 00b010
[ 3807.666713] nouveau 0000:00:0d.0: bus: MMIO write of 01c20001 FAULT at 00b010
[ 3807.688491] nouveau 0000:00:0d.0: bus: MMIO write of 03400001 FAULT at 00b020
[ 3827.179014] nouveau 0000:00:0d.0: bus: MMIO write of 046a0001 FAULT at 00b030
[ 4547.940059] usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[ 4548.362131] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=0480, idProduct=a00e
[ 4548.362144] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 4548.362150] usb 1-8: Product: External USB 3.0
[ 4548.362155] usb 1-8: Manufacturer: TOSHIBA
[ 4548.362160] usb 1-8: SerialNumber: 20140413003170C
[ 4548.363659] usb-storage 1-8:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 4548.363896] scsi host7: usb-storage 1-8:1.0
[ 4549.603244] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  External USB 3.0 0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 4549.608199] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 4570.443025] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...
```

I think that's all the relevant stuff.

I also read a suggestion about fixing corrupted filesystems with fsck, but I get a rather alarming warning and I don't want to lose the data already in the ext HD. Besides, it won't let me direct the command at the HD specifically, since there's no "sdb1" or whatever that I can use as argument.

I don't know if that might be it, but  the computer I've got the ubunte 16.04 on is an old one, only with usb 2.0 ports.

Anyway, that's all I've got so far, thank you for any help!!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like we are talking about 2 different computers as opposed to 16.04 vs 14.04, I see mention of chrome in dmesg, it may be that this computer doesn't have enough power to supply an external HD judging by dmesg getting to the point where it says 
[sdc] Spinning up disk... 
but then gets no further, if your external HD does not have it's own separate power supply then this may explain why it's not working on what I'm guessing to be a chrome book as opposed to a laptop that probably supplies more power to the USB port.